# linux kernel panic __rb_insert_augmented

Tags: linux-kernel, panic

My machine is equipped with centos7.4

Does anyone know what the problem is? I searched a lot of information but couldn't find the exact same stack.

this is output

[143576.416688] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000008

[143576.416865] IP: [] __rb_insert_augmented+0x24/0x1f0

Call Trace

```
[143576.426309] Call Trace:

[143576.426783] [<ffffffffb3ff8cbd>] ? anon_vma_fork+0xfd/0x130

[143576.427268] [<ffffffffb3fdf8ad>] vma_interval_tree_insert_after+0x7d/0x90

[143576.427764] [<ffffffffb3e947fb>] dup_mm+0x35b/0x750

[143576.428266] [<ffffffffb3e96072>] copy_process+0x1452/0x1a40

[143576.428770] [<ffffffffb3e96811>] do_fork+0x91/0x320

[143576.429286] [<ffffffffb3e96b26>] SyS_clone+0x16/0x20

[143576.429800] [<ffffffffb45761b4>] stub_clone+0x44/0x70

[143576.430321] [<ffffffffb4575ddb>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x22/0x27
```

[143576.430845] Code: 68 ff ff ff 0f 1f 00 48 8b 07 48 85 c0 0f 84 cc 01 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 55 49 89 f5 41 54 53 48 83 ec 08 48 8b 18 f6 c3 01 75 6e <48> 8b 4b 08 49 89 d8 48 39 c8 0f 84 a7 00 00 00 48 85 c9 74 05

Does anyone know what the problem is? I searched a lot of information but couldn't find the exact same stack.

Comment: This seems similar: https://gist.github.com/zerebubuth/8c88bcb6bbdaadd96fd0d076c3bd9af8 This person says it was caused by changing LBA size on an NVMe drive. (context https://github.com/openstreetmap/operations/issues/78#issuecomment-232462581) Also looks similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77314662/linux-kernel-panic-rb-insert-augmented